# Anaconda Accelerate failing with pushing to GPU

Tags: python

I recently got a gtx 1050ti for my work computer as I would like to start using my gpu to speed up some lengthy analyses. Anyway I was going through the tutorial at https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python. When I push vectorize to use my cpu every thing works fine, but when I attempt to use my gpu I receive a warning: `numbapro:1: ImportWarning: The numbapro package is deprecated in favour of the accelerate package. Please update your code to use equivalent functions from accelerate.` and an error: `NameError: global name 'warnings' is not defined`. I have looked at the accelerate documentation, but none of the libraries appear to be as simple to implement as `numbapro.vectorize`. my code is:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numbapro import vectorize

CudaOn = 1

def VectorAdd(a, b):
    return a + b

@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='gpu')
def CudaVectorAdd(a, b):
    return a + b


def main():
    N = 1000000

    A = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)

    start = timer()
    if CudaOn == 0:
        C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    else:
        C = CudaVectorAdd(A, B)

    vectoradd_time = timer() - start

    print ("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    print ("C[-5:] = " + str(C[-5:]))

    print ("VectorAdd took %f seconds" % vectoradd_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If anyone can provide a source to the accelerate documentation or how to make this work, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!